# Angular prevent multiple form submissions

Tags: angular

I would like to prevent users from being able to submit forms multiple times in my application. I built a directive that will disable the button once it has been clicked which works fine, however the button stays disabled when the form submission fails and I'm not sure how to resolve that.

The problem scenario: A user fills out the form and clicks submit. The button is disabled to prevent additional clicks. `ngSubmit` makes a `GET` request to an API which returns a response with a code outside of the 200's. My code will then look at the error, determine what went wrong, and set validation errors on the form so the user can correct the issue then try again.

However the directive has no idea what happened after the button was disabled and has no way of knowing it needs to be enabled now to allow the user to submit the form again.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appPreventDoubleClick]'
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective {
  private alreadyClicked = false;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) { }

  @HostListener('click', [ '$event' ]) onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.handleClick(event);
  }

  private handleClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (this.alreadyClicked) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      this.alreadyClicked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why not disable the button in the `component` that contains the form template?  Set disabled on the submit function being called.  Call the service and on the response from the service call, enable the button again if there is an error.  Not sure if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't really want to have to do that manually in dozens of locations and train other devs how to do it, a directive was a nice way to handle it that is simple to reuse. I might end up having to do it that way though.

Comment: @jmw5598 mentioned the more or less standard way of handling this. You can handle this with a direction, but you're going to have to add component interaction with the service which will get messy fast.

Comment: This is naturally handled by reactive forms and top-level FormGroup's `pristine`/`dirty` state, like `<button [disabled]="form.pristine">`.